# POST-request to get data from API

Tags: javascript, c#, post, fetch, webapi

I'm trying to make a login system for my API, but I can't seem to get a response back in my Javascript code. However, in POSTman, I can:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WneNm.png

This is my javascript code:

```js
function loginUser(email, password) {
    let person = {Email: email, Password: password};
    fetch(UrlAuthenticationToken, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(person),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then((response) =>{
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log(`Logged in ${response.status}`);
                return response.json(); // only for generating token
            } else {
                throw new Error(`error with status ${response.status}`);
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {

            let accessPass =
            {
                Token: reponse.Token,
                User:
                {
                    Email: reponse.User.Email,
                    Type: reponse.User.Type
                }
            }

            sessionStorage.setItem(accessPass);

            if(response.User.Type === 'Student'){
                window.href(UrlStudent);
            }
            else if(response.User.Type === 'Lector'){
                window.href(UrlLecturer)
            }
            else if(response.User.Type === 'Business'){
                window.href(UrlCompany)
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            Console.log(e);
        });
};
```

The thing is, I can send my JSON-body to the back-end and the back-end does return a response, but the front end can't seem to handle said response. I wonder what is going wrong; when I debug my code goes from the first .then all the way to the end, skipping the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "http://localhost/service.asp",
  data: {Email: "asd@asd.asd", Password: "asdasd"},
  //data: '{Email: "asd@asd.asd", Password: "asdasd"}',

  headers : {          
    "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",         
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"   
  }        
  success : function(response) {  
    Console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Seems like a function() instead of a lambda expression did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You mean this `then((response) =>{` ?

Comment: Yes, somehow that didn't work while function() worked. Blame my curriculum...

Answer (score 0):

What I see is you are using capitalize keys but in your postman I can see all the keys are in lowercase. You have used key like **response.Token** with capital T. But your response from postman seems to be like **response.token** with small t. Apart from this your code has some type mistake as well. You have misspelled response in accessPass variable.

**Your function needs to be like :-**

```
function loginUser(email, password) {
    let person = {Email: email, Password: password};
    fetch(UrlAuthenticationToken, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(person),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then((response) =>{
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log(`Logged in ${response.status}`);
                return response.json(); // only for generating token
            } else {
                throw new Error(`error with status ${response.status}`);
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {

            let accessPass =
            {
                Token: response.token,
                User:
                {
                    Email: response.user.email,
                    Type: response.user.type
                }
            }

            sessionStorage.setItem(accessPass);

            if(response.user.type === 'Student'){
                window.href(UrlStudent);
            }
            else if(response.user.type === 'Lector'){
                window.href(UrlLecturer)
            }
            else if(response.user.type === 'Business'){
                window.href(UrlCompany)
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            Console.log(e);
        });
};
```

Comment: It wasn't relevant to the error first, but afterwards it solved another issue. So, thanks!